# How to get rid of erroneously drag-n-dropped folder shortcut in Finder toolbar?

Tags: finder

I erroneously drag-n-dropped a folder shortcut in my `Finder` toolbar.  I tried dragging it off and right clicking, to no avail.  How do I remove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hold `CMD` (⌘) key down and drag the icon out of the finder window.

It should blow itself away in clouds.

Comment: Modding you up since I couldn't read worth a dang. :-)